# PHP фильтровать строку

Tags: php

Есть входная строка(ссылка), может быть вида **facebook.com/** или **http://facebook.com/** или **facebook.com/events/** и т.д.

```
$urls = [["youtube.com/watch?v=ТУТ КАКОЙ ТО ТЕКСТ", "YouTube", ["watch","likes","dislikes","comments","top"]],
        ["youtube.com/user/ТУТ КАКОЙ ТО ТЕКСТ", "YouTube", ["subscribe"]],
    ["youtube.com/channel/ТУТ КАКОЙ ТО ТЕКСТ", "YouTube", ["subscribe"]],
    ["youtu.be/ТУТ КАКОЙ ТО ТЕКСТ", "YouTube", ["watch","likes","dislikes","comments","top"]],
    ["facebook.com/ТУТ КАКОЙ ТО ТЕКСТ", "Facebook", ["subscribe"]],
    ["facebook.com/group/ТУТ КАКОЙ ТО ТЕКСТ", "Facebook", ["group"]],
    ["facebook.com/events/ТУТ КАКОЙ ТО ТЕКСТ", "Facebook", ["events"]],
    ["facebook.com/facebook/photos/ТУТ КАКОЙ ТО ТЕКСТ", "Facebook", ["photos"]],
    ["facebook.com/facebook/videos/ТУТ КАКОЙ ТО ТЕКСТ", "Facebook", ["videos"]],
    ["facebook.com//posts/ТУТ КАКОЙ ТО ТЕКСТ", "Facebook", ["posts"]],
    ["itunes.apple.com/ru/album/ТУТ КАКОЙ ТО ТЕКСТ", "iTunes", ["music_in_top","album_in_top"]],
    ["itunes.apple.com/ru/music-video/ТУТ КАКОЙ ТО ТЕКСТ", "iTunes", ["video_in_top"]]
    ];
```

Нужно проверить валидная ссылка или нет

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.filter-var.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот решение, для каждой ссылки делать свое выражение, для

```
$url = "youtube.com/watch?v=ТУТ КАКОЙ ТО ТЕКСТ";
```

Делаем так:

```
"~youtube.com/watch\?v=[^/]+$~"
```

Кусок кода `[^/]` значит Любые символы кроме / , если нужно просто любые символы тогда нужно заменить `[^/]` на `.`

Answer (score 1):

Составьте регулярные выражения для ваших строк, и проверьте на них.
Из примера не понятно за что отвечают второй и третий элементы ваших массивов. Добавьте проверку на http вначале, замените "ТУТ КАКОЙ ТО ТЕКСТ" на .* и выражение готово.

```
preg_match("#^(https?://)?youtube.com/watch\?v=.*$#", $url);
```

Если нужно проверить на то что вместо "ТУТ КАКОЙ ТО ТЕКСТ" должно быть одно из значений третьего массива, то составьте такую регулярку:

```
preg_match("#^(https?://)?youtube.com/watch\?v=(watch|likes|dislikes|comments|top)$#", $url);
```

Если нет - уточните что нужно сделать.

Comment: не работает ваш 1 код